# Update table to add a literal value to a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update/replace column values in the table with hard coded value.

> value = "c:\temp\"

This:

```
COLUMN  
file.txt  
file1.txt
```

Should become this:

```
FINAL COLUMN  
c:\temp\file.txt   
c:\temp\file1.txt
```

Attempted solution:

```
SELECT REPLACE(t.column, t.column, 'c:\temp't.column)
FROM TABLE t
```

Is this correct logic? Do we have another function I can use?

Comment: Tagging with both Oracle and tsql doesn't make any sense. Are you using Oracle or MS SQL?

Comment: Make up your mind. Is your question about Oracle or SQL Server? (TSQL is the SQL Server implementation; Oracle uses PL/SQL. Your question can't possibly be about both, as they are syntactically different.) Please use tags that are actually applicable to your question, and *read the tag definition* before using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Oracle:

If you want to change the values in the table permanently you can just run an update query:

```
update your_table
set your_column = 'C:\temp\' || your_column;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cbf42/2)

If you're using MS SQL you can do concatenation like this:

MS SQL (all versions?):

```
update your_table
set your_column = 'C:\temp\' + your_column;
```

MS SQL 2012 and later:

```
update your_table
set your_column = concat('C:\temp\',your_column);
```

Comment: Solution:update your_table
set your_column = 'C:\temp\' || your_column;

Answer (score 0):

Do a `UPDATE` statement like below in case you want to change it permanently

```
update table1 set [column] = 'c:\temp\' + [column];
```

Else, if you just want to display it that way then `SELECT` query should be

```
select 'c:\temp\' + [column] as new_col
from table1
```

NOTE: above code syntax is for `SQL Server`. Not sure since you tagged as [tsql](/questions/tagged/tsql)